# Java - deserializing a flattened XML file. (XStream, JAXB, MOXy, whichever...)

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-parsing, marshalling, xstream

I'm currently using XStream to parse an XML file but can't get it to do what I need it to do. I will change to another library if necessary, whatever can solve this problem!

Basically I'm trying to parse an XML feed similar to this:

```
<product>
  <title>Transformers Best of Grimlock</title>
  <author1>Bob Budiansky</author1>
  <author2>Simon Furman</author2>
</product>
```

Which I'm trying to parse into a model like this:

```
public class Product extends Model {

  public String title;

  public List<String> authors;

}
```

The title works beautifully but I'm having difficulty parsing the authors. Unfortunately getting the XML feed in a "more sensible" format like this is not an option:

```
...
<authors>
  <author>Bob Budiansky</author>
  <author>Simon Furman</author>
</authors>
...
```

Is there anything I can do to parse "author1", "author2", etc into a list?

Please bear in mind I'm very new to XStream (and haven't used JAXB at all!) so will need pointers on where to start if I've to write any custom binders or whatever.

Thanks for reading, I look forward to any potential solutions that may save my sanity! :)

---

**Edit:** I've updated the post to show I'm not tied to XStream. Really struggling to find the answer to this - perhaps I just don't know what to search for...

Comment: You should have a look at XPath2.0 and its builtin support for regex: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-starts-with

Comment: Thanks but I'm unsure how I can hook this into XStream? I've searched for using regex/XPath as part of the XStreamAlias annotation, but I'm not finding anything useful. Any clues?

Comment: I have never used XStream, a short gsearch showed that it can't be mapped with XPath expressions. You should consider using another XML library for serializing and deserializing XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach should work with any XML-binding library that can unmarshal from a StAX `XMLStreamReader`.  I'll demonstrate below using the standard JAXB (JSR-222) APIs. (Note:  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead).

**Product**

We'll annotate the model as if the `authors` property is mapped to the `author` element.

```
package forum11666565;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product extends Model {

    public String title;

    @XmlElement(name = "author")
    public List<String> authors;

}
```

**Demo**

We'll parse the XML document with an `XMLStreamReader`.  On that `XMLStreamReader` we'll create a `StreamReaderDelegate` that will report any elements starting with `author` as an element called `author`.

```
package forum11666565;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/forum11666565/input.xml"));
        xsr = new StreamReaderDelegate(xsr) {

            @Override
            public String getLocalName() {
                String localName = super.getLocalName();
                if(localName.startsWith("author")) {
                    return "author";
                } else {
                    return localName;
                }
            }

        };

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Product product = (Product) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(product, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<product>
  <title>Transformers: Best of Grimlock</title>
  <author1>Bob Budiansky</author1>
  <author2>Simon Furman</author2>
</product>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<product>
    <title>Transformers: Best of Grimlock</title>
    <author>Bob Budiansky</author>
    <author>Simon Furman</author>
</product>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Blaise, it's just what I needed! However when I run it I get the error "A com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException has been caught, 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions" on the line "JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);", any clues?

Comment: I updated the `Product` class in my answer to eliminate the most probable cause.  If you are using a different `Product` class than the one in my answer could you update your question to include the entire class?

Comment: Adding the extra @XMLAccessorType annotation you've put in has fixed it, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could transform the initial XML via XSLT before parsing it with XStream:

The XSLT stylesheet would transform the XML as you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="product">
        <xsl:element name="product">
            <xsl:for-each select="*[not(starts-with(name(.), 'author'))]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:element name="authors">
                <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(.), 'author')]">
                    <xsl:element name="author">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy select=".">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Funnily enough another developer here suggested this solution too! :) Though your XSLT is a lot more efficient! Gonna upvote for the code snippet, but if I can get Blaise's solution working it'll cut a step out of the process so I'll likely accept that as the solution. Thanks for the help!